# Align Label and value like Label and Input with BootStrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this my code :

```
<div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="etaord">    
<strong>Etat Ordre  :</strong> </label>
        <div class="controls">

        @if(edition){
            <select id="etaord" name="etaord" class="input-large">
            <option value=""></option>
                  @foreach (var item in Model.MINPARM001._MINPARM001.sortie.infoarg)
            {
            <option value="@item.argt" @(Model.PDDORDM002._PDDORDM002.sortie.infoordre.etatordre == @item.argt ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>@item.rubriqu.valrub</option>
            }
            </select>
           }else{
            <p id="etaord">@Model.PDDORDM002.result.sortie.infoordre.libeta.Trim()</p>
        }


    </div>
</div>
```

When i'm in the screen edition mode, the label and select field are inline.

But when i'm not in edition mode, label and value are not inline. I've a little vertical difference.

An idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap seems to expect form controls within class="controls" elements. It's a bit hacky but  adding the following css rule should work

```
div.controls p {
    margin-top:5px;
}
```